# How to againts XSS when write file stream to outputStream?

Tags: java, xss, esapi

Veracode reports that my application at the risk of XXS when writing file stream to outputStream. I am trying to use ESAPI to againts this issue, but the same problem is still reported. What should I do for this?

```
public static int copyStream(InputStream in, OutputStream out, int buffer)
        throws IOException {
    
    byte buf[] = new byte[buffer];
    int len;
    int ttl = 0;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) != -1) {
        try {
            buf = ESAPI.validator().getValidFileContent(IOUtil.class.getName(), buf, 50000000, false);
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
            ttl += len;
        } catch (IntrusionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ValidationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    out.flush();
    in.close();
    out.close();
    return ttl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If that validator is the same as [DefaultValidator](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/blob/bf46a4e7f72d2780168500a76adc2e81792feb8d/src/main/java/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultValidator.java), then it's only checking the file size. But it's checking the size of the buffer, not the file so probably won't do anything.

When sending the file to the browser, if the content-type isn't a html type then there won't be any XSS issue. If you set the content-type to `application/octet-stream` then it will be downloaded without executing anything.